# texture paint is disappearing after a while

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

[image]

hey all I am trying to paint on texture paint on the face lips , but after couple of minutes the paint just disappear and I could not see it again what is the issue and how to make it there for ever? thanks

Comment: Could you please share your blend file over blendexchange, that way it is easier to diagnose the issue? https://blend-exchange.com/